# Retrieve available fields of leads with .net toolkit

Tags: fields, .net, app-development

Well, the title says all, I need to retrieve all available fields of leads? how can that be done using developer tools for .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish a Session against the Partner API and then use the [describeSObject()](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm) to extract the information about the "Lead" sObjectType.

From the [DescribeSObjectResult](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#topic-title) the `getFields()` method will have the Field information you need.

Here you can see (a slightly modified version) of the resulting data bound to a PropertyGrid.

[image: Lead fields from the Partner API]

You can also get this data from the REST API and Metadata API.

Comment: Do you know if I can do it without this API as our company didn't want to use wsdl as they are too static?

Comment: @Vilius The Partner SOAP API isn't static with regards to the metadata about objects. If, for example, you add a new field to Lead, it will be immediately available via the Partner API. The are also REST versions of the API, if you prefer. You are still seeing exactly the same meta data.

Comment: Well I thought about using Rest API, but I will reconsider you option. Plus I wasn't clear, our client has more than one salesforce environments so their fields may differ, that's why I needed more dynamic way. When I'll choose solution I'll approve your answer

Comment: The Partner API was designed specifically for the scenario you describe. Accessing multiple Salesforce environments with different schemas. I use it it the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) to extract sObject meta data about fields and to run dynamic SOQL queries.